# Express file upload and view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload

I am using [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) to upload the images. The images are saved in my local directory. I want to insert the name of the file to the mongodb if possible. Finally I want the image to be displayed in my frontend.

```
    function insertRecord(req,res){
    if(req.files){
    const file=req.files.filename
    filename=file.name
    file.mv("./upload"+filename,function(err){
        if(err)
        console.log(err)
    })
}
    const user=new User()
    user.name=req.body.name
    user.address=req.body.address
    user.email=req.body.email
    user.mobile=req.body.mobile
    user.filename=req.body.filename
    user.save((err,docs)=>{
        if(!err){
        res.redirect('/user/list')
        }
        else {
            if (err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                handleValidationError(err, req.body);
                res.render("./users/addOrEdit", {
                    viewTitle: "Insert User",
                    user: req.body
                });
            }
            else
                console.log('Error during record insertion : ' + err);
        }
    });
}
```

I am not sure whether the way to insert the name of the file to the mongodb is correct or not. Anyway, that is optional but I am not understanding how can I display the uploaded images which are present in the local directory.
I tried to save the image as base64 but the record is not saved to the database now.

```
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
  })

  var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

router.post('/',upload.single('myImage'),function(req,res){
    if (req.body._id == '')
        insertRecord(req, res);

        else
        updateRecord(req, res);
})


function insertRecord(req,res){
var img = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
var encode_image = img.toString('base64');  
 var finalImg = {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
      image:  new Buffer(encode_image, 'base64')
   };

    const user=new User()
    user.name=req.body.name
    user.address=req.body.address
    user.email=req.body.email
    user.mobile=req.body.mobile
    user.save(finalImg,(err,docs)=>{
        if(!err){
        res.redirect('/user/list')
        }
        else {
            if (err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                handleValidationError(err, req.body);
                res.render("./users/addOrEdit", {
                    viewTitle: "Insert User",
                    user: req.body
                });
            }
            else
                console.log('Error during record insertion : ' + err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/serving-static-files-in-nodejs this might help you understand how you can show images

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I think there is a problem in the code: it should be `'./upload/'+filename' not without the second slash.

In order to show the images, you have to open a static route in Express. Example: `app.use('/images', express.static(PATH))`. Then you can, in the frontend, call it as `<img src="URL/images/FILENAME" />`

From your code, it is not possible to understand what kind of data you are sending to the server. As far as I understand, you're trying `mv` the string filename. In order to transfer files (such as images), you should have form-data instead of JSON data or you should encode the image file into Base64 to transfer it as text (not the filename, the whole file).

Check [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) out for this kind of job. It is described well in the README.md. Apart from that, until you submit the form, the image won't be available in the front-end. If you want to preview the image before uploading it's a separate process which you can learn more [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded).

Comment: Can you please check my edited post the data is not saved to database. I have converted the image to base64.